# How to deploy mvc 3 /4 using vs2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-deployment

First of all, i tried searching the web n how to do this but all of them did not work for me. Also tried the web deploy, web deploy package and file system.

What I want, if you guys may, is a simple step by step guide and the requirements of deploying a web project.

I have now a newly installed win7 (virtual machine) where I tried all of the tutorials i can find on web.

Please give me the most straightforward and easy to understand way to deploy an MVC 3 app.
Also do i need to add / configure IIS7?

project: mvc & mvc4
OS: win7 32 bit
SQL server 2008

thank you :-)

Comment: Is this tutorial series one of the ones you tried (it includes a tutorial for deploying to local IIS), and if so in what way did it not work for you?  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/introduction

Comment: Hi.  thank you for the great tutotial. Evrything worked fine for web forms, but when I try an MVC project it gives an error "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." searched all over the web but again no luck. Im using windows 8 x64, iis8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Install IIS 7
2. Ensure that IIS 7 can process ASP.NET requests. A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7).
3. Now you have two options:

   3.1 Install ASP.NET MVC on your machine. This will install the ASP.NET MVC DLL's in your machine's GAC. This is the most simple solution.

   3.2 Setup your MVC application for a so-called *bin deploy*. This will ensure that when you publish your application, the ASP.NET MVC DLL's will also be copied to the output directory. You can find a tutorial [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).
4. Deploy your ASP.NET MVC applicaton.

Your app should now be up and running! If your app still doesn't work, I suggest checking this troubleshoot guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx