# Unable to find 'publish' option on MVC 4 web application in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have created MVC 4 web application in VS2012.

Now, i need to deploy that on IIS web server.

I could not find "publish" option as we have on traditional ASP.NET application.

Please suggest me how i could publish MVC website ?

Thanks

Comment: You have the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734479/how-to-deploy-mvc-3-4-using-vs2012

Comment: Do you mean 'publish' for deploying? It is in right click menu of mvc project.

Comment: I could not find 'publish' option on right click and also not in File Menu while selecting MVC project. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really? If you right-click the MVC web app project within the solution you should have a "Publish..." menu item. This feature hasn't been dropped in VS 2012...

[image]

Comment: Its not appear in my VS 2012. I have crated  - "MVC 4 web application" project type.  it shows "convert to web application" option while right click on MVC project.

Comment: Its der now. not sure, i have created another mvc 4 app and added controller and refresh this VS.. its der now. some weired behaviour. But i can found now "publish" on that MVC proejct.

Comment: @Dhaval - if it says "convert to web application" then the project is a "Web Site" application, which isn't MVC compatible... I don't know how you could have created an MVC 4 site that was a web site project.. it just won't work...